# How can the client get the ip address of the PC?

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, websocket

I want to make a socket connection between PC and an android phone. The android phone is connecting to the PC with wifi from the PC.

This is the code of the Client.

```
try {
        socket = new Socket(IpAddress, 7890);
        toserver = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        toserver.writeUTF(message);

        toserver.flush();
        toserver.close();
        socket.close();
        return null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
```

Now, I make the ip address static(192.168.1.116 in my case). But it cannot work if I use other computers and wifi. So I wonder how can the android phone get a new ip address to make a connection with the PC over wifi.